# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local ) error

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

...

SqlConnection baglanti =new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Webflix; Integrated Security = True");

...

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        baglanti.Open();

        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select* From LoginAdmin where UserName = @P1 AND Password = @P2", baglanti);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", UsernameBox.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", PasswordBox.Text);

        SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Response.Redirect("adminpage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Wrong Username or password");
        }
}
```

I use Microsoft Visual Studio. I try to create a webpage aspx. NET Framework (Visual C#), but I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: It was a network related or instance specific error while contacting the server. The server was not found or the server is unreachable. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error has occurred. The specified LocalDB instance name is invalid)

Can someone help me please. How can I fix it?

Comment: You'd previously tagged your question with MySQL, but your code is for Microsoft SQL Server. Can you confirm if you're actually using MySQL (i.e. code is wrong) or if your tag was wrong?

Comment: yes, that was a mistake. I use Microsoft SQL Server. Should i tag?

Comment: may sound dumb, but have you actually installed and createad a localdb instance. what is the output of `SqlLocalDb info` on the command prompt?

Comment: Thats the output:
MSSQLLocalDB
v12.0

Comment: That code *implies* you are storing plain text passwords; I hope not. You should never store plain text passwords, hash them with a salt and store those in your database.

Comment: Also [can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) [It's Evil.](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: So, I am beginner of c# and mssql. That's my project. My previous project, I did my project with NetBeans Apache, and password with text format in my database. So that wasn't a problem for me.  Normally there was no error with the connection, but when i wrote this code, gives me error. So what is problem here i just need this solution.But thanks for you suggestion :)

Comment: You should also not cache your connection object, create it every time you need it from the connection string, and dispose it with `using`. Same with the reader object

Comment: *"password with text format in my database. So that wasn't a problem for me"* that is a *huge* problem! Learn from the continuous mistakes of others, there is probably at least one company a week where they expose passwords of users because they were foolish and stored them unencrypted, and stop storing plain text passwords! It's decisions like that give companies such bad PR when they get breached.

Comment: So, what type should i store password to my database? What is the safest way to do it ?

Comment: See my original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661318/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-provider-sql-network-interfaces-error-50#comment119594356_67661318).

Comment: Start with [how to store passwords safely](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/store-password-database/) - a general discussion of the concepts

Answer (score 2):

The error is with your connectstring

```
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Webflix; Integrated Security = True");
```

As you are using the [`verbatim @`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) prefix for your string, you don't need to escape the backslash. So either use

```cs
//no @ prefix
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Webflix; Integrated Security = True");
```

or

```cs
// only one \
SqlConnection baglanti =new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Webflix; Integrated Security = True");
```

And please also consider the comments of @Larnu regarding the safety of your app ...

Comment: @ToprakArat You're welcome. If the answer helped you, feel free to accept and/or upvote ...